# C code structure

Tags: c, dining-philosophers

I saw the expression below in a dining philosophers problem, and I didn't understand it. What is this style of coding called(assuming there is a special name for it)? What does the expression do? Please help explain it to me.

```
int right = i;
int left = (i - 1 == -1) ? NO_OF_PHILOSOPHERS - 1 : (i - 1);
    int locked;``
```

Below is a link to the program:

[Dining philosophers problem with mutexes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26618/dining-philosophers-problem-with-mutexes)

Comment: Aside from being a Stack Overflow question [rather than a Code Review one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), why would you tag C++ programmers with this when the original code is C?

Comment: Do you mean the [trinary operator?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C++)

Comment: Yess! I didn't know what it is called. and I don't understand the operation that takes place in the second line of code.

Answer (score 0):

The line is equivalent to the following:

```
int left;
if (i - 1 == -1) {
    left = NO_OF_PHILOSOPHERS - 1;
} else {
    left = i - 1;
}
```

Which simplifies to:

```
int left = i - 1;
if (left == -1) {
    left = NO_OF_PHILOSOPHERS - 1;
}
```

Which can also be expressed using the modulo operator:

```
int left = (i - 1 + NO_OF_PHILOSOPHERS) % NO_OF_PHILOSOPHERS;
```

The syntax with the question mark is called [ternary operator syntax](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-ternary-operator/). Which way one chooses to express the code is a matter of preference. I would not use the ternary operator here because I think it over-complicates the code by putting to much logic on the same line.

Comment: Please refrain from answering low-quality questions that are likely to get closed.  Once you've answered, that [limits what can be done to improve the question](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body), making it more likely that your efforts are wasted.  It's better to wait until the question is properly ready before you answer!

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you!